# Automatic Replace Rule for Word?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, mailing

I have a Word document which I use for Mailings and it is linked to an Excel file.

Lets say that this Excel file contains a Code (FA139, FA140, etc.) and I would like that the Word Document replaces the code with a string of text every time within the mailing feature. This means, that when I click next, it shall get the code from the Excel File and replace it with the text.

It is not purpose of the question to modify the excel file, but do all necessary changes (if possible) in the Word file.

Comment: Google "mail merge from excel spreadsheet"

Comment: You don't really provide enough information. What is the string of text? Is it different for every Code? How many are there? If there are a lot of them, where should these strings of text come from?

Comment: Sorry! For Example:
In the Excel File you have 20 different codes (e.g. FA139, FA140, etc.) and I want to assign each code a string text (FA139 = Blue, FA140 = Green). 

When I use mailing in Word, it should retreive the information from the Excel List and then within Word replace the Code with the text. 

What I use now is an IF Formula in Excel. IF in cell 1 "FA139"; Blue; otherwise: If in cell 1 "FA140; Green; otherwise: If in cell 1 "FA141; etc. etc. 

I would like to know if I can use a similar approach in Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a series of fields in Word coded along the lines of:

{IF{MERGEFIELD Code}= "FA139" "Green"}{IF{MERGEFIELD Code}= "FA140" "Blue"}

or:

{IF«Code»= "FA139" "Green"}{IF«Code»= "FA140" "Blue"}

where 'Code' is the field name.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Comment: You are the absolute best! I havent tried, but it seems very very promising. Thank you very much!